# How to iterate over two lists at once in ocaml?

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml, fold

Suppose I had the following two lists:
    let a = [1;2;3;4];;
    let b = [1;3;5;7];;
and I wanted a third list containing the index-wise sum of a and b; i.e
    let c = [2;5;8;11];;

The question is how would I do this using only functions from List.fold_right, List.fold_left and/or List.map?  (This is a homework problem, so I'm not allowed to use recursive functions or @.)

Comment: You're just giving the problem statement. What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this is a homework problem, we can really only give hints.

Let's say you wanted to use `List.map`. The type of `List.map` is `('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list`. In other words, it works on one list. If you want to use it to solve your problem, you'll have to find your own way to combine your two lists into one list. You can't use `List.map` to do this, and whatever you do to combine the lists could probably just as well do the addition for you. So this doesn't seem promising.

Now let's say you wanted to use `List.fold_left`. The type of `List.fold_left` is`('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`. The great thing about a fold is that it allows you to carry along arbitrary cumulative state of type `'a`. And it allows you to perform arbitrary modifications to this cumulative state as you work through your list.

It seems to me you could treat one of your lists as part of this cumulative state as you work through the other list with your fold.

Answer (score 3):

The `map2` function does this:

```
let c = List.map2 (fun i j -> i+j) a b;;
```

Comment: Also, `map2` works on the list with the same length, otherwise the function raises an exception

Comment: This would be a good answer, but map2 is not one of the functions that I'm allowed to use.

Comment: It's a good observation that you need to have a plan for when the lists are of different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

(* with fold_left and  @ *)

```
let (_,c)=
  List.fold_left( fun (iPos,la) ia ->
    (iPos+1,la@[ia+List.nth b iPos]) 
  ) (0,[]) a ;;
```

(* with fold_left and without @ but rev *)

```
let (_,c)=
  List.fold_left( fun (iPos,la) ia ->
    (iPos-1,ia+List.nth b iPos::la) 
  ) (List.length b-1,[]) (List.rev a);;
```

(* with fold_left and without @ *)

```
let (_,c)=
  List.fold_left( fun (iPos,la) _ ->
    (iPos-1,List.nth a iPos+List.nth b iPos::la)  
  ) (List.length b-1,[]) a
```

(* with fold_right *)

```
let (_,c)=
  List.fold_right( fun ia (iPos,la) ->
    (iPos-1,ia+List.nth b iPos::la) 
  ) a (List.length b-1,[])  ;;
```

(* with map *)

```
let c=
  let riPos=ref (-1) in
  List.map ( fun ia ->
    riPos := !riPos+1;
    ia+List.nth b !riPos
  ) a ;;
```

(* with mapi *)

```
let c=
  List.mapi ( fun iPos ia ->
    ia+List.nth b iPos
  ) a ;;
```

(* with map2 *)

```
let c=List.map2 (+) a b;;
```